Intensity of non-monochromatic electromagnetic radiation
The intensity of a monochromatic electromagnetic wave is given by
$$ I \equiv \langle S \rangle = \int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}c\epsilon_0 E_0^2  \cos^2(kx-\omega t) \text{d}t =  \dfrac{c\epsilon_0}{2}E_0^2. $$
The average is usually taken over an multiple of the period of the wave.
For a polychromatic wave, however, we may not have a time interval that is appropriate for every frequency in the spectrum of the pulse/wave (for instance, if the spectrum is a Cauchy distribution there are components of the spectrum with arbitrarilly large periods).
Also, for a monochromatic wave, it doesn't matter the initial time $t_0$ the avarage starts, since the result is the same provided the average is performed in the time interval $[t_0, t_0+T]$, where $T$ is the wave period. For a non-monochromatic wave, however, we get different values for $I$ depending on the initial value $t_0$.
What is, then, the definition of intensity for non-monochromatic waves? What should be the time interval to average? How to address the difference in $I$ due to different possibilities of intervals $[t_0, t_0 + T]$ since $t_0$ is arbitrary?
